# Xpath error related to "nbsp"

Tags: java, xml, parsing

Got this error when parsing my html page using XPATH.. i am also using HTMLcleaner

[image]

If it is not clear i can even post my java code and html code

Comment: This problem stems from treating HTML as XML and is unrelated to xpath.

Comment: XPath traverses an XML Infoset or XDM. It doesn't parse anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original input is HTML and you're treating it as XML. XML has less predefined entities than [HTML has](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML). Either use an HTML parser, or declare the entity `&nbsp;` in your XML parser, or textually replace `&nbsp;` with `&#x00A0;` in the original input.